# How do I use fix, and how does it work?

Tags: haskell, fixpoint-combinators, letrec

I was a bit confused by the documentation for `fix` (although I think I understand what it's supposed to do now), so I looked at the source code.  That left me more confused:

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

How exactly does this return a fixed point?

I decided to try it out at the command line:

```
Prelude Data.Function> fix id
...
```

And it hangs there.  Now to be fair, this is on my old macbook which is kind of slow.  However, this function can't be *too* computationally expensive since anything passed in to id gives that same thing back (not to mention that it's eating up no CPU time).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The prank answer is "fix has no real use, it's just there so you can type `fix error` in ghci and feel good about yourself."

Comment: @TomMD - Funny.  I'll remember that if anyone ever asks me what fix does and I'm feeling ornery.  :-)

Comment: I usually write `fix` as `fix f = f (fix f)`. Short, simple, works, and identical to the mathematical definition.

Comment: @newacct, yeah it's how I think of it too.  But the one here can lead to more efficient structures.  You can see the difference if you evaluate, say, `fix (1:) !! (10^8)`.  The original does it in constant memory, yours takes linear memory (which makes it quite a bit slower, too).  That is, using the let "ties a tighter knot", and allows a circular data structure to be generated, whereas yours does not.

Comment: [You could have re-invented `fix` too!](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/fix.xhtml) helped me understand `fix` a lot.

Comment: @fredoverflow's link is the BEST explanation. All the rest confuses me.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong.  `fix id` is an infinite loop.

When we say that `fix` returns the least fixed point of a function, we mean that in the [domain theory](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics) sense.  So `fix (\x -> 2*x-1)` is *not* going to return `1`, because although `1` is a fixed point of that function, it is not the *least* one in the domain ordering.

I can't describe the domain ordering in a mere paragraph or two, so I will refer you to the domain theory link above.  It is an excellent tutorial, easy to read, and quite enlightening. I highly recommend it.

For the view from 10,000 feet, `fix` is a higher-order function which encodes the idea of *recursion*.  If you have the expression:

```
let x = 1:x in x
```

Which results in the infinite list `[1,1..]`, you could say the same thing using `fix`:

```
fix (\x -> 1:x)
```

(Or simply `fix (1:)`), which says find me a fixed point of the `(1:)` function, IOW a value `x` such that `x = 1:x`... just like we defined above.  As you can see from the definition, `fix` is nothing more than this idea -- recursion encapsulated into a function.

It is a truly general concept of recursion as well -- you can write any recursive function this way, [including functions that use polymorphic recursion](http://h2.jaguarpaw.co.uk/posts/polymorphic-recursion-combinator/).  So for example the typical fibonacci function:

```
fib n = if n < 2 then n else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Can be written using `fix` this way:

```
fib = fix (\f -> \n -> if n < 2 then n else f (n-1) + f (n-2))
```

Exercise: expand the definition of `fix` to show that these two definitions of `fib` are equivalent.

But for a full understanding, read about domain theory.  It's really cool stuff.

Comment: Here's a related way to think about `fix id`: `fix` takes a function of type `a -> a` and returns a value of type `a`.  Because `id` is polymorphic for any `a`, `fix id` will have the type `a`, i.e. any possible value.  In Haskell, the only value which can be any type is bottom, ⊥, and is indistinguishable from a non-terminating computation.  So `fix id` produces exactly what it should, the bottom value.  A danger of `fix` is that if ⊥ is a fixed point of your function, then it is by definition the *least* fixed point, therefore `fix` won't terminate.

Comment: @JohnL in Haskell `undefined` is also a value of any type. You can define `fix` as: `fix f = foldr (\_ -> f) undefined (repeat undefined)`.

Comment: @Diego your code is equivalent to `_Y f = f (_Y f)`.

Answer (score 31):

I don't claim to understand this at all, but if this helps anyone...then yippee.

Consider the definition of `fix`. `fix f = let x = f x in x`. The mind-boggling part is that `x` is defined as `f x`. But think about it for a minute.

```
x = f x
```

Since x = f x, then we can substitute the value of `x` on the right hand side of that, right? So therefore...

```
x = f . f $ x -- or x = f (f x)
x = f . f . f $ x -- or x = f (f (f x))
x = f . f . f . f . f . f . f . f . f . f . f $ x -- etc.
```

So the trick is, in order to terminate, `f` has to generate some sort of structure, so that a later `f` can pattern match that structure and terminate the recursion, without actually caring about the full "value" of its parameter (?)

Unless, of course, you want to do something like create an infinite list, as luqui illustrated.

TomMD's factorial explanation is good. Fix's type signature is `(a -> a) -> a`. The type signature for `(\recurse d -> if d > 0 then d * (recurse (d-1)) else 1)` is `(b -> b) -> b -> b`, in other words, `(b -> b) -> (b -> b)`. So we can say that `a = (b -> b)`. That way, fix takes our function, which is `a -> a`, or really, `(b -> b) -> (b -> b)`, and will return a result of type `a`, in other words, `b -> b`, in other words, another function!

Wait, I thought it was supposed to return a fixed point...not a function. Well it does, sort of (since functions are data). You can imagine that it gave us the definitive function for finding a factorial. We gave it a function that dind't know how to recurse (hence one of the parameters to it is a function used to recurse), and `fix` taught it how to recurse.

Remember how I said that `f` has to generate some sort of structure so that a later `f` can pattern match and terminate? Well that's not exactly right, I guess. TomMD illustrated how we can expand `x` to apply the function and step towards the base case. For his function, he used an if/then, and that is what causes termination. After repeated replacements, the `in` part of the whole definition of `fix` eventually stops being defined in terms of `x` and that is when it is computable and complete.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very useful and practical explanation.

Comment: Love this explanation <3

Answer (score 17):

You need a way for the fixpoint to terminate.  Expanding your example it's obvious it won't finish:

```
fix id
--> let x = id x in x
--> id x
--> id (id x)
--> id (id (id x))
--> ...
```

Here is a real example of me using fix (note I don't use fix often and was probably tired / not worrying about readable code when I wrote this):

```
(fix (\f h -> if (pred h) then f (mutate h) else h)) q
```

WTF, you say!  Well, yes, but there are a few really useful points here.  First of all, your first `fix` argument should usually be a function which is the 'recurse' case and the second argument is the data on which to act.  Here is the same code as a named function:

```
getQ h
      | pred h = getQ (mutate h)
      | otherwise = h
```

If you're still confused then perhaps factorial will be an easier example:

```
fix (\recurse d -> if d > 0 then d * (recurse (d-1)) else 1) 5 -->* 120
```

Notice the evaluation:

```
fix (\recurse d -> if d > 0 then d * (recurse (d-1)) else 1) 3 -->
let x = (\recurse d -> if d > 0 then d * (recurse (d-1)) else 1) x in x 3 -->
let x = ... in (\recurse d -> if d > 0 then d * (recurse (d-1)) else 1) x 3 -->
let x = ... in (\d -> if d > 0 then d * (x (d-1)) else 1) 3
```

Oh, did you just see that?  That `x` became a function inside our `then` branch.

```
let x = ... in if 3 > 0 then 3 * (x (3 - 1)) else 1) -->
let x = ... in 3 * x 2 -->
let x = ... in 3 * (\recurse d -> if d > 0 then d * (recurse (d-1)) else 1) x 2 -->
```

In the above you need to remember `x = f x`, hence the two arguments of `x 2` at the end instead of just `2`.

```
let x = ... in 3 * (\d -> if d > 0 then d * (x (d-1)) else 1) 2 -->
```

And I'll stop here!

Comment: Your answer is what actually made `fix` make sense to me. My answer largely depends on what you have already said.

Comment: @Thomas both your reduction sequences are incorrect. :) `id x` just reduces to `x` (which then reduces back to `id x`). -- Then, in the 2nd sample (`fact`), when the `x` thunk is first forced, the resulting value is remembered and reused. The recalculation of `(\recurse ...) x` would happen with *non-sharing* definition `y g = g (y g)`, not with this *sharing `fix`* definition. --  I've made [the trial edit here](https://gist.github.com/WillNess/9569003#file-fix-question-hs) - you're welcome to use it, or I could make the edit if you approve.

Comment: actually, when `fix id` is reduced, `let x = id x in x` also forces the value of application `id x` inside the `let` frame (thunk), so it reduces to `let x = x in x`, and this loops. Looks like it.

Comment: Correct. My answer is using equational reasoning.  Showing the reduction a la Haskell, which concerns itself with evaluation order, only serves to confuse the example without any true gain.

Comment: The question is tagged with both haskell and letrec (i.e. the recursive let, with sharing). The distinction between `fix` and **Y** is very clear and important in Haskell. I don't see what good is served by showing the wrong reduction order when the correct one is even shorter, much clearer and easier to follow, and reflects correctly what actually is going on.

Comment: This real example is really useful. One can use it as a template for decomposing a recursive algorithm into `pred` and `mutate` components, which makes it straightforward to convert mathematical definitions of recursive sequences or even inductive proofs to Haskell code.

Answer (score 3):

How I understand it is, it finds a value for the function, such that it outputs the same thing you give it. The catch is, it will always choose undefined (or an infinite loop, in haskell, undefined and infinite loops are the same) or whatever has the most undefineds in it. For example, with id,

```
λ <*Main Data.Function>: id undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

As you can see, undefined is a fixed point, so `fix` will pick that. If you instead do (\x->1:x).

```
λ <*Main Data.Function>: undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
λ <*Main Data.Function>: (\x->1:x) undefined
[1*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

So `fix` can't pick undefined. To make it a bit more connected to infinite loops.

```
λ <*Main Data.Function>: let y=y in y
^CInterrupted.
λ <*Main Data.Function>: (\x->1:x) (let y=y in y)
[1^CInterrupted.
```

Again, a slight difference. So what is the fixed point? Let us try `repeat 1`.

```
λ <*Main Data.Function>: repeat 1
[1,1,1,1,1,1, and so on
λ <*Main Data.Function>: (\x->1:x) $ repeat 1
[1,1,1,1,1,1, and so on
```

It is the same! Since this is the only fixed point, `fix` must settle on it. Sorry `fix`, no infinite loops or undefined for you.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, `fix` somehow captures the essence of recursion. Other answers already do a great job at explaining how `fix` works. So let's take a look from another angle and see how `fix` can be derived by generalising, starting from a specific problem: we want to implement the factorial function.

Let's first define a non recursive factorial function. We will use it later to "bootstrap" our recursive implementation.

```
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

We approximate the factorial function by a sequence of functions: for each natural number `n`, `factorial_n` coincides with `factorial` up to and including `n`. Clearly `factorial_n` converges towards `factorial` for `n` going towards infinity.

```
factorial_0 n = if n == 0 then 1 else undefined
factorial_1 n = n * factorial_0(n - 1)
factorial_2 n = n * factorial_1(n - 1)
factorial_3 n = n * factorial_2(n - 1)
...
```

Instead of writing `factorial_n` out by hand for every `n`, we implement a factory function that creates these for us. We do this by factoring the commonalities out and abstracting over the calls to `factorial_[n - 1]` by making them a parameter to the factory function.

```
factorialMaker f n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * f(n - 1)
```

Using this factory, we can create the same converging sequence of functions as above. For each `factorial_n` we need to pass a function that calculates the factorials up to `n - 1`. We simply use the `factorial_[n - 1]` from the previous step.

```
factorial_0 = factorialMaker undefined
factorial_1 = factorialMaker factorial_0
factorial_2 = factorialMaker factorial_1
factorial_3 = factorialMaker factorial_2
...
```

If we pass our real factorial function instead, we materialize the limit of the series.

```
factorial_inf = factorialMaker factorial
```

But since that limit is the real factorial function we have `factorial = factorial_inf` and thus

```
factorial = factorialMaker factorial
```

Which means that `factorial` is a fixed-point of `factorialMaker`.

Finally we derive the function `fix`, which returns `factorial` given `factorialMaker`. We do this by abstracting over `factorialMaker` and make it an argument to `fix`. (i.e. `f` corresponds to `factorialMaker` and `fix f` to `factorial`):

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

Now we find `factorial` by calculating the fixed-point of `factorialMaker`.

```
factorial = fix factorialMaker
```