# Transforming a function that computes a fixed point

Tags: haskell, y-combinator, fixpoint-combinators, letrec

I have a function which computes a fixed point in terms of iterate:

```
equivalenceClosure :: (Ord a) => Relation a -> Relation a
equivalenceClosure = fst . List.head                -- "guaranteed" to exist 
                   . List.dropWhile (uncurry (/=))  -- removes pairs that are not equal
                   . U.List.pairwise (,)            -- applies (,) to adjacent list elements
                   . iterate ( reflexivity
                             . symmetry
                             . transitivity
                             )
```

Notice that we can abstract from this to:

```
findFixedPoint :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
findFixedPoint f = fst . List.head
                 . List.dropWhile (uncurry (/=))  -- dropWhile we have not reached the fixed point
                 . U.List.pairwise (,)            -- applies (,) to adjacent list elements
                 . iterate
                 $ f
```

Can this function be written in terms of fix?  It seems like there should be a transformation from this scheme to something with fix in it, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's quite a bit going on here, from the mechanics of lazy evaluation, to the definition of a fixed point to the *method* of finding a fixed point. In short, I believe you may be incorrectly interchanging the **fixed point of function application in the lambda calculus** with your needs.

It may be helpful to note that your implementation of finding the fixed-point (utilizing `iterate`) requires a starting value for the sequence of function application. Contrast this to the `fix` function, which requires no such starting value (As a heads up, the types give this away already: `findFixedPoint` is of type `(a -> a) -> a -> a`, whereas `fix` has type `(a -> a) -> a`). This is inherently because the two functions do subtly different things.

Let's dig into this a little deeper. First, I should say that you may need to give a little bit more information (your implementation of pairwise, for example), but with a naive first-try, and my (possibly flawed) implementation of what I believe you want out of pairwise, your `findFixedPoint` function is equivalent in *result* to `fix`, for a **certain class of functions only**

Let's take a look at some code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}                                                      

import Control.Monad.Fix                                                                              
import qualified Data.List as List                                                                   

findFixedPoint :: forall a. Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a                                                
findFixedPoint f = fst . List.head                                                                    
                 . List.dropWhile (uncurry (/=))  -- dropWhile we have not reached the fixed point    
                 . pairwise (,)                   -- applies (,) to adjacent list elements            
                 . iterate f                                                                          

pairwise :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]                                                             
pairwise f []           = []                                                                        
pairwise f (x:[])       = []                                                                        
pairwise f (x:(xs:xss)) = f x xs:pairwise f xss
```

contrast this to the definition of `fix`:

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

and you'll notice that we're finding a very different kind of **fixed-point** (i.e. we abuse lazy evaluation to generate a fixed point for function application in the [mathematical sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_theory), where we only stop evaluation **iff*** the resulting function, applied to itself, evaluates to the same function).

For illustration, let's define a few functions:

```
lambdaA = const 3
lambdaB = (*)3
```

and let's see the difference between `fix` and `findFixedPoint`:

```
*Main> fix lambdaA               -- evaluates to const 3 (const 3) = const 3
                                 -- fixed point after one iteration           
3                                  
*Main> findFixedPoint lambdaA 0  -- evaluates to [const 3 0, const 3 (const 3 0), ... thunks]
                                 -- followed by grabbing the head.
3                                  
*Main> fix lambdaB               -- does not stop evaluating      
^CInterrupted.                   
*Main> findFixedPoint lambdaB 0  -- evaluates to [0, 0, ...thunks]
                                 -- followed by grabbing the head
0
```

now if we can't specify the starting value, what is `fix` used for? It turns out that by adding `fix` to the lambda calculus, we gain the ability to specify the evaluation of recursive functions. Consider `fact' = \rec n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n-1)`, we can compute the fixed point of `fact'` as:

```
*Main> (fix fact') 5
120
```

where in evaluating `(fix fact')` repeatedly applies `fact'` itself until we reach the *same* **function**, which we then call with the value `5`. We can see this in:

```
  fix fact'
= fact' (fix fact')
= (\rec n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n-1)) (fix fact')
= \n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * fix fact' (n-1)
= \n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * fact' (fix fact') (n-1)
= \n -> if n == 0 then 1
        else n * (\rec n' -> if n' == 0 then 1 else n' * rec (n'-1)) (fix fact') (n-1)
= \n -> if n == 0 then 1
        else n * (if n-1 == 0 then 1 else (n-1) * fix fact' (n-2))
= \n -> if n == 0 then 1
        else n * (if n-1 == 0 then 1
                  else (n-1) * (if n-2 == 0 then 1
                                else (n-2) * fix fact' (n-3)))
= ...
```

So what does all this mean? depending on the function you're dealing with, you won't necessarily be able to use `fix` to compute the kind of fixed point you want. This is, to my knowledge, dependent on the function(s) in question. Not all functions have the kind of fixed point computed by `fix`!

*I've avoided talking about domain theory, as I believe it would only confuse an already subtle topic. If you're curious, `fix` finds a *certain* **kind** of fixed point, namely the least available fixed point of the poset the function is specified over.

Comment: Just noticed that there's an excellent high-level overview of the use of `fix` here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787421/how-do-i-use-fix-and-how-does-it-work that you may find useful.

Comment: So, in summary, the difference between the kind of fixed point operator I wanted and "fix" is the order of operations?

Comment: Sorry, meant to edit my previous comment, but ran out of time:  So, in summary, the difference between the kind of fixed point operator I wanted and "fix" is the order of operations?  How can Haskell even compare functions by "equality", when such an operation is known to be undecidable?  And how can we develop a fixed point operator that accepts an approximate solution, as in Brouwer's fixed point theorem for contraction mappings?

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, **it is possible** to define the function `findFixedPoint` using `fix`.
As Raeez has pointed out, recursive functions can be defined in terms of `fix`.
The function that you are interested in can be recursively defined as:

```
findFixedPoint :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
findFixedPoint f x = 
   case (f x) == x of
       True  -> x
       False -> findFixedPoint f (f x)
```

This means that we can define it as `fix ffp` where `ffp` is:

```
ffp :: Eq a => ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
ffp g f x = 
   case (f x) == x of
       True  -> x
       False -> g f (f x)
```

For a concrete example, let us assume that `f` is defined as

```
f = drop 1
```

It is easy to see that for every finite list `l` we have `findFixedPoint f l == []`.
Here is how `fix ffp` would work when the "value argument" is []:

```
(fix ffp) f []
    = { definition of fix }
ffp (fix ffp) f []
    = { f [] = [] and definition of ffp }
[]
```

On the other hand, if the "value argument" is [42], we would have:

```
fix ffp f [42]
    = { definition of fix }
ffp (fix ffp) f [42]
    = { f [42] =/= [42] and definition of ffp }
(fix ffp) f (f [42])
    = { f [42] = [] }
(fix ffp) f []
    = { see above }
[]
```