# Fix point function does not find my fix point

Tags: haskell, fixpoint-combinators

So as to understand the `fix` function, from `Control.Monad.State`, `fix :: (a -> a) -> a`, I have this little code in `modifyValue`, that increments an integer until 49, then the function always returns 50.

```
import Control.Monad.State
type StateVal = Int

modifyValue :: StateVal -> StateVal
modifyValue v | v < 50 = v + 1
modifyValue v = 50

simpleStateStep :: State StateVal ()
simpleStateStep = do
        s <- get
        put $ modifyValue s

main = do
    putStrLn $ show $ fix modifyValue
```

However when I launch this code, instead of finding the fix point at 50, where the sequence converge to 50... it claims `*** Exception: <<loop>>`

It is clear that I mistake something since I do not provide an initial state to start the sequence, for example with 1, that would generate `[2,3,4,..,49,50,50,50,50....]`

Am I using the fix function inappropriately ?
Is there something to do so as it can find the fix point 50 ?

Comment: c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4787421/356440

Comment: Formally, `fix` returns the least defined fixed point of a function. `50` is a fixed point, but so is `undefined`: `modifyValue undefined` yields `undefined`. And since `undefined` is less defined than `50`, that's what is returned. `fix` is only useful on functions that don't have `undefined` as a fixed point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well `fix` is defined something like this:

```
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

so so it's good to generate recursion for lazy data-structures

```
fix (1:) == 1:1:1:1:....
```

which works fine as list are lazy (so `take 10 $ fix (1:)` is perfectly fine)

It's not so good for pulling out a strict value from a recursive function like yours.

Because as soon as you want to print/evaluate it you need to come up with a value and this will end in an infinite-loop.

You would probably need something like

```
fixEq f x = let x' = f x in if x' == x then x else fixEq f x'
```